# Sitecore 10.3 Getting Started Template Installation Error: mssql-init stage

Tags: installation, docker, xm-cloud

When running the `up.ps1` file of the [Getting Started Template solution](https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/101/developer-tools/walkthrough--using-the-getting-started-template.html), I am getting the following error:

```
=> ERROR [mssql-init stage-1 2/2] COPY --from=headless_services C:\module\db C:\resources\jss
```

[image]

Topology I am trying to install is XP0.

Any idea how I can proceed? Thanks.

Comment: Can you share any further log details?

Comment: @GowthamarajaEswaramoorthy XP0